# Installation on USB

Tags: usb

1. Using Universal USB installer 1.9.5.2. setup the screen states `Installation done, Process is completed.` However an error message states `I couldn't find a configuration file.Ubuntu 12.04.4 desktop i386 is not supported`.  How do I fix this? I Used my MSI U100 notebook with processor atom n270 1.60 GHz, and a Memory stick Patriot XT 16GB.  Checking the memory stick I find no new content added.
2. If I install Ubuntu directly on my computer -- does it remove my Windows XP or can I switch between them ?

Answer (score 1):

1. This error message is specific to the process you are using to create the Live USB, so it's hard to know what went wrong. I suggest you try another process, there are many out there (Google). If you fail, please include more details on what commands you ran, the output etc.
2. If you install Ubuntu on your computer, you will get the option to resize your Windows partition (for example from 200 Gb to 100 Gb) and install Ubuntu in the newly freed up space, on a new partition. These two partitions will be seen almost as two physical disks by your system. Ubuntu will also detect your Windows XP installation and give you the option to boot it. A tip: if your computer runs XP it's probably pretty old. Run Xubuntu instead of Ubuntu as it has a lighter graphical interface. 14.04 is the next Long Term Support release and it's coming this April, so I would hold out for that release.

Answer (score 0):

I have nice experience with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and I recommend to use him for creation of boot-able usb stick. Is simple to use.
Yes you can install ubuntu and have windows on same pc. You must free some space on disk for ubuntu installation. Good guide for dual boot you can find on this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)